# How can I exclude a specific file from a ignored folder in .prettierignore?

Tags: prettier

In my `.prettierignore` I have the entire `amplify` folder.

```
amplify
```

Now I want to exclude from ignore (so include in prettier) some files under `amplify` folder, but I'm not sure if it's possible as `.prettierignore` syntax should be the same of `.gitignore`

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

My new `.prettierignore` should be like the one in [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/578#issuecomment-418767013):

```
amplify
!amplify/backend/function/*/src/index.js
```

But runnging `npx prettier . --check` is not including my `amplify/backend/function/myLambda/src/index.js` file.

Any hint?

Comment: Does adding a slash before dir/file names change the behavior?
`/amplify
!/amplify/backend/function/*/src/index.js`

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi sadly not, but I probably found a solution following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/5841817. I will update my answer if I can make it work.